# Status bar background color does not change to custom color

Tags: ios, swift, colors, statusbar, uistatusbar

When I change status bar background color to native UIColor.gray it changes.
But when I want to use custom color it turn black color.

`UIApplication.shared.statusBarView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray` - this code workes correct. Status bar background color is gray

`UIApplication.shared.statusBarView?.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 30/255, green: 30/255, blue: 30/255, alpha: 1)` - this code workes incorrect. Status bar background color is black

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all, set View controller-based status bar appearance property No in info.plist file.

Then add the following code in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method of AppDelegate Class.

```
extension UIApplication {
var statusBarView: UIView? {
    if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
        let tag = 5111
        if let statusBar = self.keyWindow?.viewWithTag(tag) {
            return statusBar
        } else {
            let statusBarView = UIView(frame: UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame)
            statusBarView.tag = tag

            self.keyWindow?.addSubview(statusBarView)
            return statusBarView
        }
    } else {
        if responds(to: Selector(("statusBar"))) {
            return value(forKey: "statusBar") as? UIView
        }
    }
    return nil}
}
```

I hope this would help you.

Comment: I have no idea why, but this was the only solution that worked for me of all solutions over the internet... Why such simple thing like changing status bar colour must be so complicated? Apple, are you serious?

Answer (score 5):

May this help you in Swift 4. Looks like a hacky trick but works.

You can set background color for status bar during application launch or during viewDidLoad of your view controller.

```
extension UIApplication {

    var statusBarView: UIView? {
        return value(forKey: "statusBar") as? UIView
    }

}

// Set upon application launch, if you've application based status bar
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        UIApplication.shared.statusBarView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        return true
    }
}


or 
// Set it from your view controller if you've view controller based statusbar
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        UIApplication.shared.statusBarView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    }

}
```

Here is result:

[image]

Comment: @KeghamK.- Thank you for this remark. I'll check and update as soon as I get a chance.

Answer (score 0):

The code isnt incorrect, just that the color you are providing is `dark gray` itself. `(R:30,G:30,B:30)` represents `dark gray` and thats what is being used in the `status bar`, change this color to some other color for example `(R:202,G:0,B:42)` and it will display a `red` color.

Try

`UIApplication.shared.statusBarView?.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 202/255, green: 0/255, blue: 42/255, alpha: 1)`